# C# Managed Unmanaged code

Tags: c#, unmanaged, managed

I'm trying to understand managed/unmanaged code as it pertains to structs and classes. I have a struct with a property of another struct but its a pointer declaration as in:

```
struct StateInfo
{
   Bitboard board;
   StateInfo* previous;
}
```

I'm converting a C++ project to C#. Anyways, this doesn't work because Bitboard is a class. The error I get is something to the fact that pointers cannot be declared on managed types. If I take out Bitboard from the struct, it's fine. I need it though so I changed Bitboard from a class to a struct, and all is good. I'm not sure what's up? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't even want a `struct`. Instead:

```
class StateInfo
{
   Bitboard board;
   StateInfo previous;
}
```

In C#, a `struct` is a value type. For instance, `int` is a `struct`. They should typically be used for things which are entirely described by their value.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, in c# all objects are automatically a pointer and do not need to be released.

Try reading some transitional articles about moving from C++ to C#
[C++ -> C#: What You Need to Know to Move from C++ to C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301520.aspx)

Comment: as you'll notice if you read that article, there is no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#". I'll also note for readers that the article is a decade old. Both languages have evolved in the past ten years.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about [blittability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx).

Blittable types have the same binary representation in managed and unmanaged code, and you need to represent them the same way if you want pointers to make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll check out the links for reading.